# Medium sized HD LED TV

Tags: television, hdtv

I just wondered whether anybody had a recommendation for an LED TV with these features:

- 1080p horizontal resolution.
- DVB-T2 tuner ("Freeview HD").
- 28"-32", ideally 28", but that size seems a bit neglected.
- Ability to connect PC/laptop for DVD playback (probably standard?).
- Ideally ability to record to USB.
- Ideally less than £200.

I am not interested in "smart" TVs.

I am surprised it feels necessary to ask here, but the focus seems to be on 32" and upwards. 28" seems the ideal size to me, but I struggle a bit to find these things in that size - in some cases comparable 32" TVs are cheaper, but they are a little bit too big.

Comment: You might be able to find a monitor in that size/price range. the tuner might be plaisble, but the ability to record to USB would need a smart tv

Comment: OK, I will have to do with a semi-dumb TV in that case!

Comment: Although - I have seen non-smart Sharp TVs with USB recording.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Sharp LC-32CFE5111K](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Sharp-LC-32CFE5111K-32-Inch-Widescreen-Freeview/dp/B015CZYM5Q/ref=sr_1_1?s=home-theater&ie=UTF8&qid=1464627192&sr=1-1) looks OK, if only they had a slightly smaller model.

Would also like to buy it from a real shop, but they appear not to like 28" models or recording models so much.